# Trouble Building osqp-eigen Library

Tags: c++, cmake, build, eigen3, quadratic-programming

I'm encountering challenges while building and installing the [osqp-eigen](https://github.com/robotology/osqp-eigen) library in my C++ environment. My objective is to implement a quadratic programming function similar to MATLAB's quadprog() function. However, I'm facing difficulties defining addresses for Eigen, OSQP (compiled with 64-bit integers) during the build process.

After cloning the library, I added a build folder and ran cmake .. in the command line, which resulted in a successful build:

C:\osqp\osqp-Eigen\build>cmake ..

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32822.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32822.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (9.9s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/osqp/osqp-Eigen/build
```

However, when I opened OSqp-eigen.sln in Visual Studio and attempted to build it, I encountered the following errors:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>1>Checking Build System
2>------ Build started: Project: OsqpEigen, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Building Custom Rule C:/osqp/osqp-Eigen/CMakeLists.txt
2>Data.cpp
2>Settings.cpp
2>Solver.cpp
2>Debug.cpp
2>Generating Code...
2>Auto build dll exports
2>   Creating library C:/osqp/osqp-Eigen/build/Debug/OsqpEigend.lib and object C:/osqp/osqp-Eigen/build/Debug/OsqpEigend.exp
2>Data.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol csc_spfree referenced in function "public: void __cdecl OsqpEigen::Data::clearHessianMatrix(void)" (?clearHessianMatrix@Data@OsqpEigen@@QEAAXXZ)
2>Solver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol csc_spalloc referenced in function "bool __cdecl OsqpEigen::SparseMatrixHelper::createOsqpSparseMatrix<class Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int> >(class Eigen::SparseCompressedBase<class Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,0,int> > const &,struct OSQPCscMatrix * &)" (??$createOsqpSparseMatrix@V?$SparseMatrix@N$0A@H@Eigen@@@SparseMatrixHelper@OsqpEigen@@YA_NAEBV?$SparseCompressedBase@V?$SparseMatrix@N$0A@H@Eigen@@@Eigen@@AEAPEAUOSQPCscMatrix@@@Z)
2>C:\osqp\osqp-Eigen\build\Debug\OsqpEigend.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "OsqpEigen.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Building Custom Rule C:/osqp/osqp-Eigen/CMakeLists.txt
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 10:49 ق.ظ and took 08.958 seconds ==========
```

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/osqp/osqp/issues/576) in the [OSQP](https://github.com/osqp/osqp) GitHub library that I have read, but I was unable to find the answer. Do you have any suggestions for resolving these errors

**Edited**:
I found the answer [here](https://github.com/robotology/osqp-eigen/issues/155)

Comment: Suggestion: Now that you have an answer (even if it's "Ooops. Our bad. Fixed in next rev, so update when we're done.") rather than editing the question, summarize the content of the thread on the project's bugtracker and post an answer. People seeking answers tend to not click on similar questions with no answer, so with answer it's more likely to help out the next programmer who trips over this issue.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I will not that.